# jquery get by id or cached dom node and find(id)

Tags: jquery, performance, dom, iteration

I am trying to make some speed improvements to my code and I am wondering which is a better/faster way of accessing the DOM.

I have an array of ids that correspond to < li > and i want to loop through them and add a class.

I have two ways of doing it: 
1) loop through the ids array, get element by id and apply the class

```
    for(var i=0; i<idArray.length i++){
       $('#'+idArray[i]).addClass('someclass')
     }
```

2) extract the DOM node, cache it and then loop through it, so I am only iterating on a portion of the DOM

```
    var column=$('#my_ul');

    for(var i=0; i<idArray.length i++){
       column.find('#'+idArray[i]).addClass('someclass')
     }
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You can test it yourself: http://jsperf.com/

Comment: You should have a look at [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com) and test it yourself or have a look at [this](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.7.2/jQuery.fn.find) how jQuery handles it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid a loop using:

```
 $( "#" +idArray.join( ",#") ).addClass("someclass");
```

The selector would resolve like:

```
"#" +["asd","dasd","daa"].join( ",#") 
//"#asd,#dasd,#daa"
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 should be faster. However, if these are all children of one parent, it might be a good idea to add the class to the parent.

Comment: Yes that is a good idea, the li is the parent in my case so i add the class there. Thank you